# Change scroll speed of specific element

Tags: html, css

Okay, I'm not sure how to Script this... but either in HTML or CSS is there a way to set a faster scrolling speed to any specific item?

Comment: **Sidenote:** HTML is markup and CSS involves styling via stylesheets.  Neither of which are scripting.  The only things I can imagine you would want to scroll are windows and textboxes, so if it does(n't) involve either of those, you should clarify your question.

Comment: @BLaZuRE For example I have an image and a <p>Text</p>.I want the text to go down normally when scrolling and I want the image to scroll down twice as fast as the text. So when a user on the website scrolls down, the picture will come on and go off the screen a lot faster than the text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Try using JS:**

```
function pageScroll() {
    window.scrollBy(0,50); 
    scrolldelay = setTimeout('pageScroll()',100);
}

<body onLoad="pageScroll()">
```

You can see an example [here](http://www.mediacollege.com/internet/javascript/page/scroll.html).

For a CSS solution (ie parallax), you can reference [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9752491/1427849) post.

For more information see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7408178/1427849) answer.

Comment: if I had a rep of 15 or over, I'd rate you 1 up <3 Thanksss

Comment: This answer doesn't seem to match the original question as the OP asks only about changing scroll speed (in what one would assume is the user's manual scroll speed), and it's not asking about automatically scrolling a certain distance at a certain speed.